# Receiving this error as "Min supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.4.1"

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to run

```
gradle app:dependencies
```

to check all the dependencies but the android studio is throwing this error again and again

```
Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.4.1.
```

I have tried to delete all files from my ".gradle" files inside my project folder. Also I updated the gradle.wrapper.properties path but still it's not working. I have already tried "Invalidate caches and restart" but no success even with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by dropping the folders of the oldest version in ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists and leave only the gradle-5.4.1-all

If you're using windows OS navigate to your Local Disk directory, then Users, inside the user folder open the .gradle file then wrapper then dists. Delete all the other folders leaving only the  gradle-5.4.1-all. 
I am sure this will fix your issue

Comment: Can you share your stacktrace or the error message?

Comment: @kapsid I just  edited my answer to the right solution try it out and lemme know if it works